# Select2 populate other fields on update form RAILS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that has a dropdown at the top which looks like the following

HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="psr" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">PSR</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <%= select_tag(:psr, options_for_select(@psr), class:'form-control remote-select', include_blank: true, style:"width:50%" ) %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to pull the already existing attributes from the selected field into the form and make it possible for the user to update them via textboxes. I can't quite find what I'm looking for via select 2 documentation. What's the best way to do it simply in rails using the controller/js?

Controller looks like the following:

```
  def index
    @psr = {}
    CircuitVw.where("activity_ind IN ( 'Pending', 'In Progress')").order("document_number DESC").each do | circuit |
      @psr[ "#{circuit.psr}  -  #{circuit.customer_name}" ] = circuit.psr
    end
```

And the rest should just populate dynamically based on this selection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
@psr =CircuitVw.where("activity_ind IN ( 'Pending', 'In Progress')").order("document_number DESC")
<%= select_tag(:psr, options_from_collection_for_select(@psr, 'id', 'customer_name'), class:'form-control remote-select', include_blank: true, style:"width:50%" ) %>
```